# PowerShell - Use variable in another cmdlet

Tags: string, variables, powershell, active-directory

I want to create a variable with the office phone number of an AD user and use this variable in another cmdlet.

```
$a = Get-AdUser -Filter "name -eq 'User1'" -Properties OfficePhone | FT OfficePhone | Out-String
Set-ADUser User2 -EmailAddress $a
```

I tried this one, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = (Get-ADuser User1 -Properties OfficePhone).OfficePhone
Set-ADUser User2 -EmailAddress $a
```

The -Properties parameter of Get-ADUser tells the cmdlet to include the properties you specify *in addition to* the other properties it already includes, such as DistinguishedName,Enabled,GivenName, etc.

Because of this you have to specify which property you want saved to the $a variable by wrapping the cmdlet in parentheses and using a period followed by the property name. This is actually the same thing as:

```
$a = Get-ADUser User1 -Properties OfficePhone
$b = $a.OfficePhone
Set-ADUser User2 -EmailAddress $b
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the specific property of the User1 object, in this case OfficePhone. Please try that and let me know if it works as I don't currently have the Active Directory modules installed.

```
$a = Get-AdUser -Filter "name -eq 'User1'" -Properties OfficePhone | Select-Object OfficePhone
Set-ADUser User2 -EmailAddress $a
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but it doesn't work either. I got the following error.
   Set-ADUser : "System.Object[]" kann nicht in den Typ "System.String" konvertiert werden, der für den Parameter "EmailAddress" erforderlich ist. Die 
angegebene Methode wird nicht unterstützt.
In Zeile:2 Zeichen:37
+ Set-ADUser User2 -EmailAddress $a
+                                     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Comment: Okay so it's saying that $a is an object and therefore cannot convert it into the string required for the -EmailAddress parameter. Try:

    Set-ADUser User2 -EmailAddress $a.OfficePhone

Comment: Can you comment the second line out with # and write $a | Format-Table -Autosize on the third line. This will hopefully provide the properties and values stored in $a.

Also comment out the Select-Object OfficePhone so the line reads $a = .... # | Select-Object etc...

Comment: Now I get: DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID and OfficePhone from User1.

Comment: Can you do $b = $a.OfficePhone
$b | Format-Table -Autosize

I have a feeling that the OfficePhone property is an object containing other properties.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :( Sorry, but my powershell is in german, so here the error in german: In Zeile:3 Zeichen:21
+ $b = $a.OfficePhone $b | Format-Table -Autosize
+                     ~~
Unerwartetes Token "$b" in Ausdruck oder Anweisung.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Sorry put the $b | Format-Table -Autosize on a new line